# how to find the integral of a generalization of the Gaussian: exp(-abs(x)^q/2)

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I am currently self studying through Bishop's pattern recognition and machine learning. I've hit a bit of a road block on exercise 2.43, and I'm hoping someone will be able to assist.

The problem is to prove that:

$$p(x\lvert \sigma^2, q) = \frac{q}{2(2\sigma^2)^{1/q}\Gamma(1/q)}e^{-\frac{\lvert x \rvert^q}{2\sigma^2}}$$
is normalized. I know how to take care of the absolute value of course:

$$2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^q}{2\sigma^2}}$$

but... man. I apparently need to review my calc. I remember seeing a name for this kind of integral, but it was maybe a year ago, and I can't seem to find it again. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This dang question only has a one star difficulty, so maybe it's something stupid I'm just missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up the exponent on $e$ by using the change of variables $t:=x^q/(2\sigma^2)$, i.e., $x=(2\sigma^2t)^{1/q}$, so that $dx=\frac1q(2\sigma^2t)^{\frac1q-1}(2\sigma^2)dt$. This transforms your integral into
$$
\frac2q(2\sigma^2)^{1/q}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\frac1q-1}\,dt.
$$
To finish off, use the definition of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):
$$
\Gamma(z):=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt
$$

Comment: well shit. Thanks friend, I should probably sleep on problems before hitting stack exchange. I appreciate the help.